# How to get Future[\/[Throwable, T]] from several Future[\/[Throwable, T]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

Assuming I have several methods to return `\/[Throwable, String]`. The right value `Int` is what I want and the left value accumulates errors.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
type ErrorOr[T] = \/[Throwable, T]

def init(a: Int): ErrorOr[Int] = a.right
def add(a: Int, b: Int): ErrorOr[Int] = (a + b).right
def multiply(a: Int, b: Int): ErrorOr[Int] = (a * b).right

init(3).flatMap(add(_, 4)).flatMap(multiply(_, 3)) // 21
```

It looks good, because scalaz either's flatmap is right biased, so it will operate based on the right value.

However, if method is going to change for the API call, so the return type would be `Future[ErrorOr[T]]`. Is there any way I can use to return `Future[ErrorOr[T]]`? Also, I probably want to use `future.flatMap` as a callback instead of using `await` here to block

```
def init(a: Int): Future[ErrorOr[Int]] = Future(a.right)
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Future[ErrorOr[Int]] = Future((a + b).right)
def multiply(a: Int, b: Int): Future[ErrorOr[Int]] = Future((a * b).right)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the result of `init` in the `EitherT` monad transformer, use `flatMapF` instead of `flatMap` to use `add` and `multiply` directly like you do now, and then call `run` to get `Future[ErrorOr[Int]]` back:

```
EitherT(init(3)).flatMapF(add(_, 4)).flatMapF(multiply(_, 3)).run
```

Comment: This answer would be better with the naming of all of the categories involved, and where they're coming from. Like `EitherT` being a monad transformer, as already done, but also for `flatMapF`, and for whatever `run` is.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using [`scalaz.concurrent.Task`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.0.4/doc/#scalaz.concurrent.Task):

```
def init(a: Int): Task[Int] = Task.now(a)
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Int] = Task.now(a + b)
def multiply(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Int] = Task.now(a * b)
```

So:

```
scala> val res = init(3).flatMap(add(_, 4)).flatMap(multiply(_, 3))
res: scalaz.concurrent.Task[Int] = scalaz.concurrent.Task@3fdb3076
```

Can be easily converted to:

```
scala> res.get
res1: scalaz.concurrent.Future[scalaz.\/[Throwable,Int]] = ...

scala> res.get.run
res5: scalaz.\/[Throwable,Int] = \/-(21)
```

If you need to fail:

```
scala> def add(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Int] = Task.fail(new RuntimeException("fail"))
add: (a: Int, b: Int)scalaz.concurrent.Task[Int]

scala> init(3).flatMap(add(_, 4)).flatMap(multiply(_, 3)).get.run
res4: scalaz.\/[Throwable,Int] = -\/(java.lang.RuntimeException: fail)
```

Please note, that the `Future` here is `scalaz.concurrent.Future`

Update

If you need to pass `Either` to the Task - you can use this:

```
import Task._

implicit class FutureToTask[T](f: Future[\/[Throwable, T]]){
   def task = async(f.runAsync)
}
```

Comment: I like to use Task. However, it also means that I need to throw exception in my code instead of catching it as an Either left value. Do you think this is a good idea ?

Comment: Something like `import Task._; Task(5.right.fold(fail, now)).join` might convert it, or you can use `Task.async`

Comment: I agree that it looks tricky, I hope we can get more convinent tasks from comig fs2 library